# window. location stuck looping

Tags: jquery, loops, window, window.location

I am trying to change a div's background colour based on what page the window is on using

```
 if(window.location = "web.html"){
    $("#webweb").css("background-color", "grey")
}
```

but the page just goes into a loop of verifying that is the page and wont let me click anything.

Comment: Another one with `=` vs `==` vs `===`. [Why are robots killing Hoomans](https://s28.postimg.org/v1ys31kzh/robooooo.png)

Comment: with == the styling is not applied

Comment: Check what `window.location` returns. Try `window.location.pathname === 'web.html'`